# NSMutableAttributedString in UILabel with alternate baselineOffset

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a case where I want to display some sort of Footnote-Text in a `UILabel`. The text is prefixed with a number as the corresponding index.

My first idea to solve this problem was to simply create a view-setup with an `UILabel` for the mark and the text each. This, however, involved a lot of fiddling with constraints and auto-layout, since I wanted to list all footnotes in a table.

Thus I came up with the idea of using `NSMutableAttributedString`  and set the baseline/font-size for the mark and the text respectively. The resulting `NSAttributedString` could then be used in any Layout with an `UILabel`.

```
let footnote: NSMutableAttributedString = .init(string: mark, attributes: [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.myColor,
                .font: UIFont.myFont(7),
                .baselineOffset: 10,
            ])
            disclaimer.append(.init(string: text, attributes: [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.myColor,
                .font: UIFont.myFont(14),
            ]))
```

Or so I thought. Seems like the layout of either the `UILabel` or the `UITableViewRow` do not like text with alternating baselines, as the `UILabel` never resized to more 2 Lines. Everything beyond those 2 lines was cut off. Even setting the `preferredMayLayoutWidth` to help the layout out a bit did not work. It did scale the Label to the correct height, but the text was still missing as if it was cut-off.

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my own question (and to share this knowledge with whoever might stumble across the same problem), I was able to solve this problem with a very simple (admittedly not very elegant) fix.

All I had to do was to add some text before my mark with the modified `baselineOffset`. This way, the layout seems to be able to calculate the correct height while still rendering the mark and text properly. Since I did not want any additional text in my cells, I've used a `Zero-Width Space` character.

```
let footnote: NSMutableAttributedString = .init(string: "\u{200B}", attributes: [:])
            footnote.append(.init(string: mark, attributes: [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.myColor,
                .font: UIFont.myFont(7),
                .baselineOffset: 10,
            ]))
            footnote.append(.init(string: text, attributes: [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.myColor,
                .font: UIFont.myFont(14),
            ]))
```